# visibility among templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I've got two classes, TwoWayVector and TwoWayVectorIterator, as the names imply, I'm trying to implement my own vector class and an iterator for it. I seem to be having some visibility issues, and I'm also not sure how to construct a TwoWayVectorIterator from a method TwoWayVector.begin();

TwoWayVector.cc

```
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class TwoWayVector{
public:

T* data;
int capacity;
int nextFree;

TwoWayVector(){
    capacity = 10;
    nextFree = 0;
    data = new T[capacity];
}

~TwoWayVector(){
    delete data;
}

T& operator[](const int index){
    if( index >= capacity || capacity + index < 0){
        string number = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << index) )->str();
        string error = "index " + number + " is out of bounds"; 
        throw error;
    }
    else if(index < 0){
        return data[nextFree+index];
    }
    return  data[index];
}
 //memory leaks?
void push_back(T object){
    if(capacity <= nextFree){
        capacity = capacity*2;
        T* tmp = new T[capacity];
        for(int i=0; i<capacity; i++){
            tmp[i] = data[i];
        }
        delete data;
        data = tmp;
    }
    data[nextFree] = object;
    nextFree++;
}

T pop_back(){
    nextFree--;
    T result = data[nextFree];
    data[nextFree] = NULL; 
    return result;
}

int size(){
    return nextFree;
}

TwoWayVectorIterator begin(){
    TwoWayVectorIterator<T> iterator= new TwoWayVectorIterator<T>(0,this);
    return (iterator);
}

};
```

TwoWayVectorIterator.cc

```
using namespace std;

template <class T> class TwoWayVectorIterator{
public:
TwoWayVector<T>* vector;
int currentPosition;
TwoWayVectorIterator(TwoWayVector<T>& vec){
    currentPosition = 0;
    vector = vec;
}
TwoWayVectorIterator( int pos , TwoWayVector<T>& vec){
    currentPosition = pos;
    vector = vec;
}

bool& operator==(const TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
    bool address, position;
    address = (&vector == &vector2) ? true : false;
    position =(currentPosition == vector2->currentPosition) ? true : false;
    return (address && position);
}

bool& operator!=(const TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
    bool address, position;
    address = (&vector == &vector2) ? true : false;
    position=(currentPosition == vector2->currentPosition) ? true : false;
    return (address && position);
}

TwoWayVectorIterator& operator++(){
    currentPosition = (currentPosition+1);
    return *this;
}
TwoWayVectorIterator& operator++(int){
    currentPosition = (currentPosition+1);
    return *this;
}
TwoWayVectorIterator& operator=(TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
    &vector = vector2;
    currentPosition = vector2->currentPosition;
    return *this;
}
TwoWayVectorIterator& operator+(int n){
    currentPosition = currentPosition+n;
    return *this;
}
TwoWayVectorIterator& operator-(int n){
    currentPosition = currentPosition-n;
    return *this;
}
bool& operator<(TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
    return (currentPosition<vector2->currentPosition);
}
T& operator*(){
    return vector[currentPosition];
}
};
```

called from Test.cc

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "TwoWayVector.cc"
#include "TwoWayVectorIterator.cc"

int main(){

TwoWayVector<int> numbers;
numbers.push_back(3);
numbers.push_back(2);
numbers.size();
TwoWayVectorIterator current = numbers.begin();
return 0;
```

}

compiler errors:

```
In file included from Test.cc:3:
TwoWayVector.cc:59: error: ‘TwoWayVectorIterator’ does not name a type
Test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cc:18: error: missing template arguments before ‘current’
Test.cc:18: error: expected `;' before ‘current’
```

I've tried forward declaring a couple different ways, different schemes of inclusion, and calling TwoWayVectorIterator current = numbers.begin() , but I don't want to have to specify the type for the iterator.

Any help here is immensely appreciated!!

Comment: Include `TwoWayVectorIterator.cc` in `TwoWayVector.cc` and then include only `TwoWayVectorIterator.cc in Test.cc`

Comment: And forward declare `template<typename T> class TwoWayVector;` in `TwoWayVectorIterator.cc` at the top.

Comment: Also `TwoWayVectorIterator` is a template class. So it needs to be called like `TwoWayVectorIterator<sometype> current = numbers.begin();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First problem:**

It seems you haven't `#include`d the file which contains the definition of `TwoWayVectorIterator` from file `TwoWayVector.cc`, which uses its definition in function `begin()`.

Try adding this directive:

```
    #include <sstream>
    #include "TwoWayVectorIterator.cc"
^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Second problem:**

Inside `TwoWayVectorIterator.cc`, you will have to put a forward declaration to make it aware of the existence of `TwoWayVector`:

```
template<typename T> class TwoWayVector;
```

**Third problem:**

Also, in function `begin()` you are using `TwoWayVectorIterator` as the return type without specifying the necessary template argument:

```
TwoWayVectorIterator<T> begin(){
//                  ^^^
    TwoWayVectorIterator<T> iterator= new TwoWayVectorIterator<T>(0,this);
    return (iterator);
}
```

**Fourth problem:**

Your `main()` function suffers from a similar problem:

```
int main()
{
    TwoWayVector<int> numbers;
    // ...
    TwoWayVectorIterator<int> current = numbers.begin();
    //                  ^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

**Fifth problem:**

Another issue is that the constructor of `TwoWayVectorIterator` should accept a *pointer*, not a reference, to `TwoWayVector` (at least judging from how you are using it):

```
TwoWayVectorIterator( int pos , TwoWayVector<T>* vec){
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    currentPosition = pos;
    vector = vec;
}
```

**Sixth problem:**

Your overloads of `operator ==` and `operator !=` are returning a *reference to* a temporary `bool` object, which will eventually get destroyed when the function returns, leaving you with a dangling reference and resulting in Undefined Behavior as soon as you try to dereference it.

You should just return a `bool` instead:

```
    bool operator==(const TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
//  ^^^^ 
//  Return by value here!

        // ...
        return (address && position);
    }

    bool operator!=(const TwoWayVectorIterator* vector2){
//  ^^^^
//  Return by value here!

        // ...
        return (address && position);
    }
```

---

**Related advices:**

Besides, you should avoid having such `using` directives at global namespace scope:

```
using namespace std;
```

This is importing all the names from the `std` namespace into the global namespace, potentially resulting in undesired name clashes.

As a further general advice, avoid giving your variables name of standard container classes (such as `vector`). Choose something like `myVector`, or `innerVector`, or whatever you think fits best as a descriptive name.

Moreover, you should follow naming conventions and give your header files and implementation files extensions such as, respectively, `.h` (or `.hpp`) and `.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! when I tried this it gave me the following  errors:                                                       `In file included from TwoWayVector.cc:2,
                 from Test.cc:3:
TwoWayVectorIterator.cc:6: error: declaration of ‘class T’
TwoWayVectorIterator.cc:4: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
Test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
Test.cc:17: error: missing template arguments before ‘current’
Test.cc:17: error: expected `;' before ‘current’`

Comment: @agarrow: I updated the question again. With all the fixes, your code now compiles for me

Comment: @agarrow: I copied all the code [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SRz1U$164). You can see it compiling.

Comment: @agarrow: I actually found a further problem. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I’m tempted to downvote this – the `.cc` extension, like `.cpp`, marks an *implementation* file, you should *not* include those. Of course that’s only by convention but you should *not* break these conventions, there are good reasons for them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Go ahead, I don't mind downvotes as long as they come with a reasonable explanation. Of course I do agree that using non-standard extension is a bad practice, but I glossed over it as it was not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Well of course I’d prefer having that fixed in the answer. ;-) By the way, sorry, that sounds a bit like a stupid threat, it wasn’t meant like that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I did not take it as a threat ;) Everything that helps improving my answers is welcome, including downvotes. I mentioned this  in the "Related advices" anyway

Comment: @AndyProwl I can't thank you enough. Not only have you fixed my problem, but I've learned a lot from you're response. What a great community this is!